# Does it matter which key is considered private and which public?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, rsa

Mathematically, is there a difference which set of characters is private_key and which one is public_key?

@Edit
At the moment of asking I was thinking on RSA, not asymmetric crypto in general.

Comment: Can we add more clarification here about if this is talking specifically about RSA or about asymmetric crypto in general?  It makes a huge and potentially catastrophic difference.

Comment: See also [a similar question on Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43894/public-key-cryptography-misunderstanding).

Answer (score 12):

**Shouldn't necessarily matter...**
In RSA you can use either d (private) or e (public) to encrypt and also decrypt. This doesn't work with all cryptosystems. For example DSA won't allow this.

So technically it wouldn't really matter if you exchanged the values of e and d.

**...but does**
**Performance:**
But actually you usually want verification (using e) to be fast. And then accept that signing (using d) is slower.

Usually the public exponent is picked to be some simple and small binary representation. The number [65537](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)) (0b10000000000000001) is regularly picked as the public exponent. And a much, much larger (about the same size as the modulus, so about 2048 bits nowadays) number as the private key.

See also: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537

**Security:**
And: You can't really flip this around (large public exponent, small private exponent), because there are published attacks on small private exponents. ([Wiki: Wiener's attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener's_attack))

See also: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/why-should-the-rsa-private-exponent-have-the-same-size-as-the-modulus

Comment: Keeping one of the exponents small is a choice made for performance reasons. But there never was any freedom in choosing which of the exponents would be small. A small private exponent and a large public exponent would be insecure, because then the private exponent can be brute forced. So the performance optimization achieved from the small exponent can only be used for the public key. There is a different performance optimization which can only be used for the private key, because it relies on knowing the factorization.

Comment: Published attacks against small exponents don't matter. Trying all of them is in range now.

Comment: @Joshua: I don't understand. Are you saying *"Pick any private exponent length and any modulus length you want, RSA is broken anyway."*? (In that case my answer would be: *"I'd need to see some research on this first."*)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff: Trying all primes less than 24 bits doesn't take all that long and I'm pretty sure with a few boxes I could do 32 bits fast enough.

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes. With many asymmetric cryptosystems, one of the keys can be derived from the other one, so there is no choice as to which one to keep private.

Many asymmetric cryptographic algorithms are based on the difficulty of computing [discrete logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). The private key is an integer *k* and the public key is the value *g*<sup>*k*</sup> for some public parameter *g* in a space where the discrete logarithm computation is infeasible with large numbers, but exponentiation is reasonably fast. This is the case for example with numbers modulo a large number *p*: calculating *g*<sup>*k*</sup> mod *p* from *g* and *k* is straightforward, but solving the equation *g*<sup>*k*</sup> mod *p* = *y* for *k* is infeasible when *p* is chosen appropriately (a prime with additional properties depending on the algorithm). Then, for acceptable key sizes, it's easy to calculate the public key from the private key, but there is no known method to calculate the private key from the public key in human-scale time. Two popular algorithms based on the difficulty of discrete logarithm are [DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (including their elliptic curve variants — DSA and DH rely on the difficulty of calculating logarithms in ℤ/pℤ, ECDSA and ECDH in elliptic curves over finite fields).

There is one popular family of cryptosystems where the private key and the public key live in the same mathematical space and the operations treat them identically: [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). At the core of RSA is the operation *M* ↦ *M*<sup>*k*</sup> mod *n*, in which *k* is the private key *d* for decryption and signature and the public key *e* for encryption and signature verification (*n* is a public parameter, and the security of RSA requires picking different *n* for each key pair). Calculating *d* given only *e* and *n* is infeasible if the values are properly chosen. It is possible to generate an RSA key pair where the two exponents are interchangeable. However, this is rarely done because there is a performance advantage to choosing a small value for *k*. Therefore, in practice, RSA uses a small value for the public key *e* and the corresponding value for the private key *d*. The small value has to be the public key, because if the private key was small, it could easily be found by brute force (*d* cannot be calculated from *e*, but it is easy to validate whether a guess of *d* matches the known values for *e* and *n*, so safety relies on having an impossibly large search space for *d*).